# Prevent roomba from deleting questions tagged announcement

Tags: feature-request, meta, automatic-deletion

Meta posts are frequently used by moderators / staff to make announcements. Sometimes these announcements are not so popular (have negative scores) and don't receive any answers either causing roomba to delete them. This has happened multiple times recently: [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/423143/timeline), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/422975/timeline), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/425530/timeline).

Given that we probably want these announcements to stay, roomba should ignore posts tagged [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement). To prevent this from being abused the [announcement](/questions/tagged/announcement) tag should potentially be made moderator-only.

Credits to [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) for the [idea](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56097479#56097479).

Comment: I wonder if locking them would prevent the deletion. Community bot has mod privileges, so I'm really not sure.

Comment: @Laurel:  Locks would prevent the Roomba from firing off, yes, but it'd be more problematic than that.  What good does it to do Meta to have a locked announcement?

Comment: @Makoto history is most certainly useful, even if the announcement is unpopular. What would be problematic is the fact that noone can interact with it then.

Comment: @KevinB:  So...we should encourage less commentating on announcements and more answering then?  Because again, in this very, *very* edge-case scenario, all someone needs to do is answer an announcement to ensure it's never deleted.

Comment: @Makoto in general i think feedback should be encouraged to be presented as an answer, absolutely, but i still think announcements posted as questions that fail to do so shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: But, neither of your examples currently have the [meta-tag:announcement] tag. If we're using tags, maybe it would be better to have an explicit tag, perhaps something like [meta-tag:status-no-roomba-deletion], or a less verbose name. Probably better would just be a new lock type like a "no deletion lock".

Comment: @Makyen well the idea is that mods / staff then remember to add that tag. I do like the idea of a new lock type though. Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Couldn't mods just... offer some trivial self-answer to the question to defeat the Roomba?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that's what has been done in the examples shown, but that happens **after** the deletion has already happened, it also assumes that someone is going to notice the deletion of these posts.

Comment: I mean, now that the problem has been identified, such answers could be posted *preemptively*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That would mean moderators would need to keep track of every such post and add an answer on the last day (Probably won't want to add the answer too early in case someone else answers). This could be semi-automated with something keeping track of these. But then, it might as well be built into the system.

Answer (score -14):

I feel very conflicted about this idea.

On the one hand, announcements are in a separate league of their own; with the Stack Exchange platform having to do some extra stretches and bends to get discussions that aren't *exactly* Q&A to work, it makes some sense that these questions would be treated slightly differently.

On the other hand...this kind of occurrence only really happens when people don't think the announcement or discussion of the announcement are particularly *good*, or it doesn't survive the [surprisingly low barrier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) it needs to avoid the Roomba in the first place.

So I have to wonder, is this hand wringing over a circumstance which *tends* to not be an issue?  What of the staff making these announcements; knowing the limitations of the system, what are they doing to ensure that their announcement-style questions aren't removed by the system?

(Maybe they *do* belong on a blog post if they're being pruned by the very system they're meant to be supporting??)

Comment: I mean, it's certainly fair to look at this as evidence that the posts staff are making here under announcements aren't adequately engaging the audience here such that more than 23 people felt it worthy of a vote and a bunch of comments but not an answers, but i think that's somewhat of a different discussion from whether or not unpopular announcement posts that didn't engage the community enough to warrant an answer should be deleted

Comment: Well, I'd rather have an announcement here, which I then can ignore, instead of having a blog post and an announcement mentioning that blog post or a banner mentioning. That they post on their blog and hope that it will reach many users without going to meta seems rather unlikely, imo.

Comment: @KevinB:  I disagree.  Both posts have a decent amount of *comments* underneath them which would've made suitable *answers* in the spirit of the meta discussion being had about these announcements.  Some nudging to get people to *answer* instead of *comment* would have helped us avoid this entire plot.  Furthermore, if the intention is to post it on this platform and have it adhere to the same rules of said platform, then it is not unreasonable to expect the question to engage the community in ways more than just voting.

Comment: @Tom:  I don't exactly see the difference.  The blog post gives the illusion of being informed.  The Meta post gives the illusion of being heard.  The pattern I've seen over the last few announcements is that a decision has been made and we're being looped in for awareness rather than being asked if it were good or bad.  I mean, *that* right *there* is more indication that you'd get people answering, and if *we're not getting that*, then it's not the Roomba who's to blame, I say.

Comment: @Makoto We have quite similar opinions here. The best solution, in my point of view, would be they post only on their blog, but I don't see this happening in the near future. The part where our opinions differ is on "deleting". Even when an announcement wasn't well received and didn't get any answers, it is still something one might need to remember/find later, especially when it is regarding rules on Stack Overflow (or Stack Exchange). It is rare that rule changes don't get any answers, yes, but if that's the case then they shouldn't be hidden from a large portion of users.

Comment: @Tom:  Again, the threshold is *literally* someone answering the question.  That's all that's needed to prevent the question from being Roomba'd on Meta.  If the announcement isn't capable of generating enough interest for people to answer it, or the staff isn't engaged enough to answer it themselves *if only for the sake of preventing it from being Roomba'd*, I don't see deletion as the worst fate for those announcements. I may drum up a query later on to see just how many times this has occurred but I really don't feel that based on this *alone*, that we shouldn't delete "dead" announcements