# New Collective: NLP – Scope, community, and questions

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement, nlp-collective

Today, the [NLP (Natural Language Processing) Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp) is launching on Stack Overflow.

### Why NLP?

Both question activity and pageviews pointed to the NLP space as one that has been consistently active for Stack Overflow, even before the era of generative AI. This area of practice continues to be one that attracts new learners and finds new applications, and that dynamic makes a good foundation for a subcommunity space.

There are a few potential discussion topics to dive into now. Please feel free to respond to any of these prompts, or to suggest others. Discussions here could be spun off into standalone questions as needed. (Please use the tag [nlp-collective](/questions/tagged/nlp-collective) for any new questions specifically about this collective.)

### Tags and scope

The tags currently being used to define the collective are: [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp), [spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy), [spacy-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spacy-3), [nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nltk), [huggingface-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/huggingface-transformers), [word-embedding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word-embedding), [sentiment-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sentiment-analysis), [named-entity-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/named-entity-recognition), [tf-idf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tf-idf), [bert-language-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bert-language-model), [topic-modeling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/topic-modeling), [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp), [opennlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opennlp), [gensim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gensim), [word2vec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word2vec), and [nlp-question-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp-question-answering)

**Do these feel like the right tags? Are there any that seem missing, or any that don’t belong?**

The focus brought by a collective brings an opportunity to assess the set of related tags and have conversations about optimizing them.

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nlp/info) for [nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nlp) lists two NLP-specific tags, [sharpnlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharpnlp) and [clearnlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clearnlp), that are not heavily used (with 9 and 2 questions, respectively, and none from the last few years). **Should these be added to the collective, or are these more appropriate for consolidation or some other kind of “cleanup”?**

**Should the tags [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search) and [information-retrieval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/information-retrieval) be part of this collective?**

Also see [this discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76946062/scope-tag-change-proposals-for-nlp-collective) in the collective.

### Content needs and community concerns

**What are potential projects that the NLP collective members might collaborate on to improve the experience for both askers and readers of NLP questions? Can any resources be improved to reduce duplicate questions and help askers avoid posting off-topic questions?**

Some community members may be concerned that the existence of the collective itself could inadvertently encourage off-topic questions. **Are there ways to better route those potential askers to the appropriate Stack Exchange site, if there is one?**

If you’re active in the tags and have found yourself wishing for improvements in some area, post your thoughts about what the ideal scenario might be. Even if it seems unrealistic, often that can be a great starting point for ideation and meaningful change.

### Recognized Members

Recognized Member (or “RM”) is the [user role](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types) specific to Collectives that has additional privileges, most notably to designate specific answers as “recommended” and to oversee the review and publication of articles. It is intended for those who would be considered subject matter experts in the collective’s topic, or perhaps in some specific portion of the topic. While we generally see the RM group as the community leaders within each of these collectives, it’s up to the community to decide how the role operates in that regard.

The Recognized Member role in the NLP Collective will be open to any user with a gold or silver badge in one of the collective’s tags, and who has not been suspended in the past 12 months. Anyone who qualifies can express their interest in a comment or answer on this post. Those interested are also welcome to inquire about the RM role via the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?topic=15) if they feel more comfortable that way.

However, the Recognized Member role is not required to be part of helping define how the collective operates. The first step in being involved is participating in the discussion on this post!

### General questions

The NLP Collective is intended as a space for a subcommunity to grow and thrive in ways that make sense for this area of practice. Community members well-versed in NLP are best suited to determine how to leverage the current features of the collective and to identify the areas that could most benefit from further development.

**If you’re active in the NLP tags or in a related Stack Exchange community, what questions do you have about the collective? What opportunities or challenges do you see ahead?**

Please note: the answers and discussion here are intended to be specific to the NLP Collective. If you have thoughts or feedback about collectives in general, please share those on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425532/launching-2-new-collectives-php-and-nlp) instead.

Comment: What's supposed to be accomplished by this, that isn't accomplished by the fact that [ai.se] exists?

Comment: There appear to be fewer than 40k questions total across all of these tags. That's fewer than e.g. [tag:haskell] has by itself. Not really convinced this qualifies as "consistently active for Stack Overflow, even before the era of generative AI".

Comment: Is  `NLP` selected to have a concept/technology in the mix of collectives as opposed to `C#` for instance? Is this choice based on the fact that provider collectives are focused on a set of technologies, not a single programming language? Same goes for `CI/CD`.

Comment: @M--ßţřịƙïñĝ Yes, the term we've been using is "area of practice" since that can include specific technologies but doesn't need to be exclusive to them, and be inclusive of different areas of focus within the broader area of practice (beyond what might be in a single tag).

Comment: See [Stack Overflow trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends/?tags=nlp%2Cspacy%2Cnltk%2Chuggingface-transformers%2Csentiment-analysis%2Cstanford-nlp%2Cgensim%2Cword2vec%2Chaskell) -- these tags aren't very active (most don't show up on trends since they have fewer than the 2k question threshold necessary to qualify). I plotted them against Haskell, which is a sideline tag with little activity (a couple/few questions a day). Try against a major language or framework if you're curious.

Comment: I might be biased since I work on that but I think the `haystack` tag should be part of the collective too. Most of the [asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haystack) are already part of the NLP collective cause of some other tags but I think it would beneficial adding `haystack` too.

Comment: Are there some good exemplary NLP questions? I have never seen any (most seen *by chance* seemed to be too broad and/or underspecified), but maybe I never went to the right places/corners.

Comment: @PeterMortensen creating such a list, similar in some ways to what's been done with the [tag:r-faq] tag, is a likely early project for the collective. An upcoming feature will facilitate that very nicely.

Comment: @ggorlen--onLLMstrike The topic is indeed niche in comparison to others, looking at total volume. Our research shows that the NLP topic is amongst the fastest growing in popularity among topics within the broader AI/ML ecosystem and cuts across other popular tags related to various disciplines and languages. We looked at traffic and the web of tag relationships as well as activity, to determine that a defined subcommunity space could be appealing.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a placeholder answer to prevent this staff post from being
> automatically deleted.
>
> Please remove it if there are ever any actual answers to this
> question.

See this post for context: [Prevent roomba from deleting questions tagged announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423719/prevent-roomba-from-deleting-questions-tagged-announcement)