# Who is going to handle flags on content in the Collectives discussions feature?

Tags: support, flags, moderation, collectives, discussions-space

A new site area for subjective discussions has been announced in the WeAreDevelopers talk and [on SO Labs](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/discussions/), scheduled for release in August 2023. My understanding is that the feature is just for collectives. Who is going to be tasked with moderating that content? I assume that regular users with flagging privileges will be able to flag things, but who will be tasked with handling those flags?

Comment: Here's hoping there are flags.

Comment: I read it as ***only*** applying to the [NLP Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425530/new-collective-nlp-scope-community-and-questions) (and an experimental feature), at least in the first instance. Or was it just used as an example?

Comment: @PeterMortensen the talk video shows NLP, and the SO Labs page just says "collectives".

Comment: @PeterMortensen the NLP collective is the crash test dummy. From what I understand, it'll get it first, and depending on how bad it goes, it may or may not spread

Comment: Why not an AI ? :)

Comment: @M-- this feature _is_ related to Overflow AI. It was announced as being _part of_ the Overflow AI project, and is listed so in SO Labs in the page I linked. Did you just not know that? Or do you know that and still think it's not related to Overflow AI?

Comment: @starball I am aware of the announcement and how it was framed. The reason it got attached to Overflow AI is that they launched the Discussions with the NLP Collective. Now, that this feature spread to other Collectives, regardless of the shattered "crash test dummy", this question doesn't need to be attached to Overflow AI, IMO. So, to be clear, I don't think you made an error when you tagged this question with O-AI, but I suppose the feature "evolved" to be related to all Collectives :facepalm:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Current info

See [Discussions update: Expansion to all tags in February](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427864/11107541). Quoting [Berthold](/u/18279858):

> Through March, we’ll also be working to further define what is, for now, an informal role on Stack Overflow – the “Discussions moderator.” With the moderation toolset separate from what’s in place for Q&A, we’re able to extend moderation of Discussions to community members who have volunteered to help “pilot” this role. In addition to assessing and handling flags, these moderators can edit, delete, and undelete Discussions posts. They cannot suspend users or redact content.
>
> Right now, this group consists of Stack Exchange site moderators, Recognized Members from community-managed collectives, and users who’ve been highly engaged with Discussions by offering feedback and putting effort toward curating the content. Future conversations within the community can focus on how users become part of this group and what might be expected from them.
>
> Discussions moderators are: **[Abdulla Nilam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla-nilam), [Laurel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel), [M--](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6461462/m), [Thomas Markov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11032967/thomas-markov), [Wicket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1595451/wicket)** (updated 1/24/24). For now, this list will serve as the official roster for this group and will be updated by Community Managers as needed. As an informal group that is part of the Discussions experiment, Discussions moderators are not yet denoted by badges or other visual role designations. All Stack Overflow site moderators also have access to all Discussions moderation functions, and are welcome to moderate as they see fit, but are not obligated to do so.

#### Older info

Quoting from [Discussions experiment launching on NLP Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426107/11107541) (which is about a specific early experiment with the feature, and I assume is not necessarily representative of how things will work long-term),

> For this experiment, we’ve built the moderation functionality in a self-contained way within the Discussions feature. Any user with the flagging privilege can flag a Discussions post.
>
> Community Managers will moderate the space. While Stack Overflow moderators will have access to all moderation capabilities in Discussions, there is no expectation for moderator oversight of this new content type. Moderators can take any action on users or content that they feel is necessary; Code of Conduct violations are not viewed any differently for Discussions. A collective’s Recognized Members do not have moderation capabilities in Discussions.

Answer (score 12):

In an internal announcement posted today (and it's the right feature this time, not the private discussions with the exact same name but a completely different purpose; thanks for naming stuff sanely, Stack /s), they confirmed that staff will be handling flags. Similarly to the private discussions feature (that had a grand total of 6 non-staff posts over two months spanning 6 collectives a few days ago), mods do have access to tools, but we've been told we're not expected to handle anything there.

Flags are mentioned, but the details of them are not. They also go on to say that it'll have a very basic moderation system, and rather expand it if it graduates. It does not say who gets to flag. <strike>I'd imagine everyone with the flagging privilege, but wouldn't surprise me if they bound it to collective membership or something annoying like that.</strike> Everyone can flag, as confirmed by staff [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425795/who-is-going-to-handle-flags-on-content-in-the-overflowai-discussions-feature/425861#comment968214_425861)

Incredibly optimistic to base a public feature on the very limited CM workforce if you ask me though, but whatever. Wouldn't surprise me if the answer shifts in the future. We'll see

Comment: Flagging will indeed be available to anyone with the flagging privilege, regardless of collective membership.

Comment: @IanCampbell The public discussions feature hasn't been released yet, and it'll only be released to the NLP collective for the test. You have access to private discussions, a different feature by the same name, which doesn't have flags. The flag button redirects to the "contact us" form. It's also fully moderated by staff