# Expanding Discussions: Let's talk about curation

Tags: discussion, collectives, announcement, discussions-space

### UPDATE: Dec 13, 2023 - Discussions flag reasons are now available.

---

This week, we are expanding the Discussions experiment to the [R Language](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/beta/discussions), [CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions), and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions) Collectives. Moving beyond the [initial launch in the NLP Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) allows for more participation across the different areas of practice. With a link to a Discussions home page (featuring Discussions in all collectives) soon being [added to the left navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392163/design-vision-updates-to-the-left-navigation), and through other discovery paths we’ll be exploring, we expect to see more participation in Discussions as time goes on.

More activity and content will bring added focus to the curation processes for this new type of content. The purpose of this post is to open up conversation about the norms and needs around curation, flagging, and content organization.

#### A fresh start with Discussions flags

Discussions is a new content type. When building out the initial experiment, we didn’t want to assume that the same flagging reasons and systems from Q&A should be applied. From both a social and technical perspective, there were strong reasons to take a fresh approach with flags and be guided by what we see.

The Q&A moderation dashboard and systems are complex; flags and their resolutions become part of user history, and can affect things down the road for those users. While utilizing the same conventions and tooling might have had advantages, we did not want to make users reluctant (or overzealous) to flag things in Discussions due to uncertainty about how those Q&A flag types apply to this new space. Making changes to the current systems (and the code that powers them) for Discussions might also have unintended effects on Q&A processes, and we did not want to disrupt those moderation flows or make life harder for the Stack Overflow moderation team.

#### Help us determine the right flag types

The “green field” approach and current bare-bones tooling have caused some concern, which is understandable. So let’s dive into some of the open questions and see what parameters and options we can define together. This ongoing conversation is concurrent with what we’ll observe as Discussions usage increases, and we’ll apply those learnings and the conversations here toward a solution that can meet community needs and help maintain content quality. The [Discussions guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines) can also evolve accordingly.

Let’s imagine the modal that might appear when someone decides to flag a Discussions post. **What flag reasons should be displayed as options for the flagging user to choose from?** For each item below, I’ll pose some open questions (in bold) which are the things I hope we can discuss further in answers and comments.

Some options are clear-cut. We should have the following flags:

- **Spam**
- **Rude/abusive behavior** (largely inclusive of most Code of Conduct violations)
- A **free-form text field**, to provide insight when there’s not a clear predefined reason. This can also provide a path for the clear-cut but possibly more rare scenarios like “no longer necessary, the parent reply is deleted” and help us determine if those are common needs. **Proposed label: “Something else”** (as seen on the comment flag modal)

Some other possible options for flag reasons may not be as clear-cut. Let’s talk about other scenarios that we’ve seen mentioned in user feedback already. As we look at these, let’s also remember that **feedback about a Discussions post can also be provided in replies**. Discussions is a conversation space, and it’s okay to let the author know *how* the post might be improved. That visible interaction may help others, in addition to the author, understand more about what makes a post high-quality.

- **This does not belong here** – This could apply to both blatantly off-topic content as well as relevant posts that might be better suited for another location (like Meta, or another Stack Exchange site).

  - **What are some potential labels or “reasons” that would cover these scenarios?** Or would this scenario be better handled with the free-form text field? This is also an area where we can explore automated solutions or migrations in the future.
- **Duplicates** – It’s interesting to consider how this scenario might differ from Q&A. Some Discussions posts may feel similar to older, existing ones, but the ensuing conversation on each post can be very different depending on the wording of the post, recent changes in the area of practice, and the specific users that end up participating. Both the older and newer posts can have standalone value even if they are similar in some ways. Applying the same guidelines and processes that govern duplicates for Q&A may not be the best approach. This may be an area where conventions coalesce organically over time, or perhaps different collectives might take varying approaches to the issue based on the specific subject matter. Future additions such as sorting/filtering and search can also be helpful as the number of posts grows over time.

  - **Should “duplicate content” be a pre-set flag reason, or does it make more sense for a potential flagging user to bring that up in a reply instead?**
  - **Does the free-form text field option cover things well enough here, allowing the flagging user to specify what is being duplicated?**

**What other reason options would you like to see appear on a flag modal for Discussions?** As I said before, this will be an ongoing conversation and open for productive contributions for a long while.

---

See [this answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426412/expanding-discussions-lets-talk-about-curation/426929#426929) for a revised proposal for the Discussions flag reasons modal. Feedback can be provided in the comments on that answer.

Comment: What is the point in curating this?

Comment: I kept flagging one of the discussions in the NLP collective, as it was off-topic, and even explained so in multiple comments, one of which were to your reply, @Berthold. Yet my flags just kept getting declined, it seems like.

Comment: @AndreasismovingtoCodidact Yes, that post was itself an experiment in what is and isn't off topic for Discussions, kind of in a gray area. Your flags (and reply) were definitely registered as feedback. This does bring up a sub-topic of this post, as well -- feedback for the flagging user. The Q&A flag system provides for this to some degree. Aside from some kind of confirmation that the flag was seen/processed, would you have felt better knowing more about why it was declined? Would you have re-flagged it regardless?

Comment: Great, so this new shiny feature that supports selling a paid product gets promptly called out in the UI, ignoring chat yet again, despite one being a proven long-term useful feature and the other being... not. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Berthold I was mostly just baffled you didn't just reuse the Q/A system, with proper flags, with a new entry in the flags list on the profile. But then again, the already existing flag system has some drawbacks that I'm sure you can find feedback for on Meta already. It's not so much about what I feel, but the consequences of that flag. I have seen some of the arguments made for declining such a flag, and I don't think they hold up. But seeing my flags get declined for reasons I disagree with? Well, that's obviously not motivational. Regardless, I'm not going to participate in these

Comment: discussions. My participation was as much an experiment, as the Discussions feature was, well except that my experiment had an expiry date. So, as I don't actually care for this feature; no, I wouldn't continue flagging. I did it as an experiment, not because I am invested in the feature, and because I genuinely care about it. I have given up this platform, but was curious to see what this was. Again, not because I believe in the purpose, but because it was fun to play with. That fun has ceased.

Comment: @Berthold But, speaking of flag feedback, considering that these were discussions, and not Q/A, you actually could have addressed my flags in a reply to the discussion, with a ping to me, and explained why they were declined. I already provided feedback stating that the discussion was off-topic, _and_ repeated it, so you wouldn't really be disclosing any private information by revealing to the public that I had also flagged it.

Comment: **This does not belong here**. You should seriously consider that option. If you are really invested in this, it makes sense to add at least 3 options: (1) Belongs to Meta (2) Belongs to the main Q&A site (3) Off-topic for SO altogether - Meta, Main Q&A, or Discussions. I would not talk about other sites, since it is not fair to drop something from the experimental features of SO on their lap. Duplicate? I don't think there's much harm in including that, but how useful it'll be? Gotta wait and see if Discussions expand enough so we run into dupes. Not necessary for now I guess. Cont'd ...

Comment: ... But all of this comes to down to the questions asked by multiple users: Who's going to curate this? And What's the expected outcome of said curation? p.s. That said, I appreciate you bringing this up for "discussion".

Comment: The flagging UX for discussions is... pretty bad. Confirmation upon clicking but no follow-up choices to choose _why_ we want to flag something? No ability to retract? The flag doesn't even show up in my profile flag page of pending/cast flags.

Comment: When you mention duplicates, do you only mean duplicates within discussions or also duplicates with existing Q&A? Anyway, I too feel that curation should be rather on the light side. Let it flow. Just make sure people are nice to each other. Discussions are basically just a bit more focused chats. I would not expect to find reliable information in a discussion (although it may be in there).

Comment: @M-- "What's the expected outcome of said curation?" Higher quality discussions? Isn't that the expected outcome of all curation activity everywhere to separate sand from pearls?

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution higher quality? if quality existed in the topics being described as being relevant to discussions they'd already be a part of Q&A.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution what is higher quality in the realm of discussions? Certainly it's not being focused and specific. I don't wanna discuss whether that's good or bad, but one needs to define higher quality (not a term I'd use, but just quoting you) to get the desired results. A lot of people mow their lawns, some just want it short, some want stripes, waves, etc.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Sand is the new pearl. More sand = more engagement = more activity. Doesn't have to be shiny.

Comment: @M-- Let's call the quality insightfulness. It's the thing that makes readers of discussions say, yes, that was worth the time. Curation would try to filter out those discussions that rather lead nowhere and reading them is a waste of time. Maybe if we look at existing discussions we find out which of them we would like to keep and which not and develop some suitable criteria from there.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I am after specifics. General phrases like "insightfulness" or "quality" do not translate into any measurable curation guidelines.

Comment: @M-- Sorry, cannot deliver more. But the idea of looking at many examples of discussions and develop measurable curation guidelines from these examples isn't that bad.

Comment: Imo this question is way too broad. What should we moderate (what's allowed and disallowed, e.g. the duplicate content example), who will moderate what, and how will we design the flag dialogs are 3 broad discussions. Answering the last without having consensus/a decision on the first two doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would personally like to see "spam" renamed to "spam or hidden advertising" though, or a variation thereof. The Stack Overflow interpretation is just so much more intricate than what most of the internet thinks is spam.

Comment: @M-- [Who is going to handle flags on content in the OverflowAI discussions feature?](/q/425795/11107541) cc. ErikA

Comment: @starball That made sense for the beta, but if we want to do it properly, we should first determine _how_ we want to curate before determining _who_ will handle the flags. If we want to move questions that fit well on Stack Overflow to Stack Overflow, for example, we probably won't want CMs making those judgement calls, but SMEs that have close vote privileges instead, since we can't expect CMs to know R + PHP+ all other languages that get a discussions section. My point is: this is a stepwise process, and this question is trying to do all steps at once, so will fail at getting proper answers

Comment: As I have mentioned in other Meta discussions, if any flagging pertains to redundant content, then instead of the emotionally and semantically triggering "_Duplicate_" word, perhaps use "_elsewhere_" -- as in "_Resolved Elsewhere_" or "_Discussed Elsewhere_".

Comment: It will be interesting what the company makes out of the feedback for discussions that is given here and in related meta questions. Discussions are used as far as I see but quality varies. What bothers me most actually is not the curation but why upvoted content is not sorted on top. Am I really expected to scroll through the whole discussion? For me this severely limits the usefulness of the feature. I want to get to know the most useful contributions and I want to get to know them quickly or not at all.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Reply sorting is now available (as of last week), and one of the options is to sort by score. Sorting on the whole list of posts is in progress.

Answer (score 122):

Moderating this is a paradox.

We have been trained and disciplined for over a decade to regard conversational content as unceremoniously off-topic, and this helps keep our heads on straight and keeps the cats well-herded.

By its very nature, moderating discussions will require several orders of magnitude more context and investigation into what a discussion was *really* getting at, and will require even more investment from the volunteers to be able to identify what's OK and what's not OK.

I don't think you can set your veteran curators [on content like *this*](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/beta/discussions/77085087/which-r-is-the-best-base-tidyverse-or-data-table) which should immediately evoke [Gorilla vs Shark](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/)-level visceral reactions.

...but what if it's OK?  How do we know it's OK?  We haven't spent any time in that collective to know intuitively, and if we had something automated keeping an eye out for things like this (a-la Charcoal), all of those heuristics built up on the rock-solid foundation that **chit-chat was not what we optimized** means we have to rebuild those heuristics.  From ***scratch***.

I think the right way to declare how these are meant to be moderated is to reinforce what purpose they serve, and the kinds of content that they're *expected* to have.  Without that guardrail, we're nowhere near close to even getting started on doing this right.

Comment: I mean, this is only true, if there is any real definition of "value" that these discussions must abide by. By it's very nature, discussions provides no real "value" outside giving users a place to ask for free volunteer research that produces answers that begin to lose their usefulness the moment they're posted. What value is there in moderating discussions for "value", if there is no long-term value to be had there?

Comment: @KevinB:  You don't need to have "value" if someone's posting links to spam or CSAM, you need to take *action*.  That's what *moderation* is about.  *Curation* on the other hand determines the overall value of the thing that's posted, and that's what the arrows should do.

Comment: With that in mind, maybe the only flags that belong on discussions are the most obvious, i.e. the Spam, R/A, and Mod flags. That way, "on-topicness"/ scope isn't even on the table, but CoC violations can still be handled.

Comment: @zcoop98:  Fair, but now we get into the second half of the point I was making earlier - who's gonna do all of this?  Right now the volunteer curators are so geared up in one context that asking them to shift to this new context is going to go about as quickly as molasses in July in Antarctica.  To complicate things, the community is pretty good at automating stuff like this, and it feels like there's this...expectation...that the same thing is done here for this kind of content.  I don't think it'll translate well.

Comment: The question 'who's gonna do all of this?' is great. But the main point is not that volunteers have enough work with curating Q&A or that they are accustomed to different curation criteria. It's why should they care about discussions being curated? Do they need them, do they bring any value to them?

Comment: @TadeuszKopecforUkraine given the community has no ability to curate it, it won't be.

Comment: I was once told that bank tellers are trained to detect counterfeit bills by shuffling through thousands of real bills. Their fingers grow so accustomed to what a real bill feels like that they develop an intuitive ability to sense when they touch a counterfeit bill. Whether or not this is true about bank tellers, I think it's a useful analogy for moderating content. Unless you have a well-developed sense for what a **good** post looks like, trying to describe all the ways in which a post can be **bad** is just a waste of effort.

Answer (score 33):

Blatantly off topic could be useful for... say, someone asking a question about jQuery in the R discussion, but given the nature of discussions... anything loosely related to R would be on topic there, even if it would be better posted as a typical Q&A or otherwise would be *way* off topic, such as what to study to become an R developer.

Discussions by its very nature produces content that is unlikely to be useful long-term... that's why these topics aren't allowed in the general Q&A area to begin with. I don't see much reason to be concerned with curating it at all outside of dealing with CoC violations given it's not a tool for producing long-term useful content. Why even have votes? They certainly don't indicate usefulness in this case.

Comment: "They certainly don't indicate usefulness in this case." And they don't influence the sort order. Higher scored discussion contributions aren't shown on top but strictly within the timeline. The votes really seem useless. Discussions look a bit like Reddit, but not as good.

Comment: If anything, id' prefer to see the votes removed and replaced with stars and/or reactions. There's enough confusion about what voting is for without discussions using them as a popularity contest while mislabeling them as useful/not useful.

Answer (score 21):

[You already wrote guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines)... Why not just make flags for those guidelines?

> - Programming-specific questions that belong in Stack Overflow Q&A
> - Discussions about the Stack Overflow experience broadly
> - Sharing or requesting information about specific courses/bootcamps/certifications without substantive discussion
> - Career advice or posts about open roles
> - Posts focused solely on networking or professionally connecting with others
> - Event announcements
> - Reviews of what it's like to work at relevant companies or for specific people in the field

Either make a flag reason for each, or group some related ones together, or just make a single flag reason that points toward those guidelines.

---

On the point of closing duplicates, ... I'm glad you brought it up, but the only reaction that thinking about this brings up in my mind is a milder form of despair. By all means, try it. If duplicates are left untouched, then you'll get something like reddit, where things get re-hashed endlessly (info will end up more scattered and harder to find), and they even go as far as enabling auto-archiving things after a period of time (forcing re-hashing). To be clear, I'm not a great fan of what I think will be likely outcome if duplicates are closed either. Stack Overflow was at least partially created to solve the problem of having to slog long threads of discussion / pages of documentation, and having to piece things together, and forget irrelevant info to finally get something of value (not that duplication closure would cause that, but it- as another evil- might help make it worse).

Comment: Does a specific "does not follow the guidelines" option make sense, when they have the "something else" option to provide details already? Though having that standalone "does not follow the guidelines" option is an opportunity to offer another link to the guidelines, which could be helpful. Since the guidelines could change over time, we probably want to avoid having specific wording reproduced in the flag modal by listing out each one.

Comment: @Berthold do what you think best. If you're going to wrap them all as one option, then make that option its own flag reason instead of expecting people to think to custom flag and post a link to the guidelines. that's not intuitive and I think you'd miss a lot of guideline-breaking because of that.

Comment: I think that makes sense -- and I edited my comment, I was thinking that the "does not follow the guidelines" flag option's text would be a great place to link to the guidelines.

Answer (score 17):

After seeing blatant spam sitting for over a day in Mobile Development discussion space (yes, it was flagged) I am completely baffled that company like Stack Overflow that knows what kind of problem spam represents, managed to implement a new feature without thoroughly thinking about moderation first.

If nobody else, they should know that the second you put an edit box on Internet it is only matter of time before someone starts posting spam there. Moderation is not and should not be an afterthought, it should be the first and foremost thing you define. Especially, dealing with spam.

That also raises another question, who can moderate the discussion space. Will the diamond moderators have the ability to handle posts there, or this will be solely left to CMs and Collective admins?

**Update:** We are now at day 3 of following spam still being visible in the Mobile Development Discussions. On the site that commonly deals with spam in matter of minutes, if not seconds.

It is beyond obvious, that any new feature that would allow posting on sites, **MUST** include spam flag support from the day one. Not only that, elected community moderators also **MUST** have ability to moderate such content. Community Managers and other staff cannot efficiently handle those.

[image]

Comment: Spam and countermeasures are always part of development when there’s a new form of contribution being added. As you’ve seen, we’re proceeding with a specific spam flag which will allow us to implement automated behavior for that scenario going forward.

Comment: Elected SO mods do have the ability to handle Discussions flags, but as it is outside their normal workflow, and Discussions is still in an experimental phase, we do not expect them to be taking that on. For now, Community Managers are doing the vast majority of moderation in Discussions.

Comment: The volume of spam has been low thus far, relative to Q&A. That said, the visible posts you noted were an unfortunate side effect of the American holiday last week, and we do apologize for the delay in getting them taken down. As we continue to evolve the Discussions experiment, improvements in moderation is a significant focus.

Comment: @Berthold The volume of spam has been low, because nobody knows that Discussions exist. People that have been here for decades don't know about them. So you were lucky, because only handful of spammers knows about them, too. But you cannot depend on luck alone. I have seen how spam attacks here look like, and if you accidentally had such over the holidays, it would have been ugly.

Comment: "_the second you put an edit box on Internet it is only matter of time before someone starts posting spam there_" the SEO juice (or what remains of it) attracts them like flies

Comment: see [Who is going to handle flags on content in the Collectives discussions feature?](/q/425795/11107541)

Answer (score 16):

Based on the feedback on this post, conversations with community members and collective Recognized Members, and our own observations and moderation of Discussions, we’re proposing the following flag reasons for Discussions posts:

[image: image of proposed flag modal for discussions posts that includes options for: spam, rude or abusive, should be a question, something else (with free form text field and link to discussions guidelines)]

[image: image of proposed flag modal for discussions posts that includes options for: spam, rude or abusive, should be a question, something else (with free form text field visible)]
*Showing text field when "something else" is selected*

Please provide any feedback here, especially if you have been active in the Discussions spaces.

**Update - November 15, 2023** - the proposed modal has been updated per recent feedback. We have consolidated "unrelated to the collective" and "community-specific reason" into the "something else" reason, retaining the visible link to the guidelines.

**Update - December 13, 2023** - Discussions flag reasons are now available.

Comment: why does "something else" say "action by a moderator"? I thought it was [CMs who were handling discussion flags instead of mods in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425795/11107541)? (yes, I know CMs are also mods, but not all mods are CMs).

Comment: @starball Regarding "action by a moderator", it's meant in a generic sense -- the people who are moderating these discussions and will see this flag. We're sensitive to the fact that listed site mods may be seen as the ones taking action (or not taking action) and other suggestions are welcome here too.

Comment: We can include the site name in the wording, as in the other places this is used when presenting a guidelines-based flag option -- "This post doesn't meet the Stack Overflow discussions guidelines". With the link to the guidelines (in the Stack Overflow Help Center) there, that would be pretty clear. What do you think?

Comment: yes, "Stack Overflow discussions guidelines" is better. my next concern is that that very help center page includes prohibition of spam, and "discouraging" SO questions in discussions, so while one can intuit-it out, it could be confusing as to whether to use that flag reason for those things, or the dedicated flag reasons.

Comment: Indeed, all of the items above the guidelines option are things addressed in the guidelines. We expect that if the flagging user sees an option that clearly fits the situation, they won't need to review or refer to the guidelines to make any further determinations. So we don't think it will be confusing. In the future if we add other layers of options branching from specific selections, we could rethink the flow and where each item belongs.

Comment: What does the "a community-specific reason" do? Based on my experience with the close / flag dialog, I would expect it to go on to a set of reasons set by the SO moderators. But those don't strike me as relevant to discussions. Would "not meeting one of the discussion guidelines" make more sense?

Comment: @IanCampbell or to also handle the other problem I pointed out: "not meeting one of the other discussion guidelines"

Comment: @Berthold It's a rather minor change, but I'd suggest capitalizing the (bolded) flag options for consistency with the main site. Also, is there a reason for opting to use 
"something else" instead of the standard "In need of moderator intervention" for the last one? Lastly, It might be worth italicizing "Be specific and detailed" for consistency with the main site, too.

Comment: why do you need a free-form text field for a flag reason for the discussion guidelines? ideally, shouldn't the discussion guidelines should be clear enough that it should be sufficient to say that it doesn't meet a guideline, and for the flag handler to figure it out?

Comment: @starball the "something else" option isn't *only* for guidelines-related concerns. We need a way for the flagger to provide more details if they choose, for all the many things that we can't think of right now. That context is vital; "flag handler [can] figure it out" is not a scalable moderation approach.

Comment: When will this flagging be implemented? You have **spam** sitting in MD discussion for over 11 hours now.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to all who have contributed to this conversation so far. Below is a consolidation of some of the replies/sentiment, as well as some things that we’ve observed, and some thoughts on each one.

- **Concern:** Curation takes multiple forms: Flags, votes, text feedback to the author. It feels limiting to focus just on flags right now.

  - Agreed! We started the conversation focused on flags because those can at least cover some of the most common scenarios, and building flagging also needs the most lead time, in terms of development. But all forms of curation are open for ideation here. (Starball, for this reason, I have reverted your title edit, though I understand why you made it).
- **Concern:** The meaning of votes can seem murky, especially in the absence of defined flag reasons/options. And especially when votes may have different meanings for Q&A that may or may not be applicable. Does it make sense to use voting here?

  - This is a question we asked internally during development as well. In the [demo video](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/discussions/) (showing a potential future design), you can see that there are other types of reaction/sentiment signals there. This is definitely a place we can iterate and experiment, and it’s a key part of curation; more input is welcome.
- **Concerns:** What is the point in curating Discussions? Who's going to curate this? What's the expected outcome of said curation?

  - Valid questions! For the space to have ongoing value, there should be ways to signal what content is most valuable/useful. As already noted, there are many potential ways to do that. The community as a whole can send signals in multiple ways. Sometimes that will be enough – **reply sorting will be available soon**, which will offer readers a way to see the best replies. Flags give a signal to a smaller group, those who moderate/assess the posts, to determine if something should be removed (or perhaps edited) to maintain quality and utility.

    - Reply sorting options will be: Recent activity, Highest score, Date created (oldest or newest). Nested replies will always show in chronological order. **Are there additional filters or sorting options you'd like to see to posts or replies?**
- **Issue:** Discussions posts that should/could be questions

  - We are seeing this happen, often from newer users, and are assessing the best approaches to help with the issue. In some cases, we’ve seen that the authors do receive helpful answers. In some cases, community members and Community Managers encourage authors to post to Q&A. In some cases, we’re deleting the posts, and it’s worth noting that authors can still access their deleted posts via links from reply notifications. So a reply right before deletion can be a helpful tool for letting the author know what happened.
  - **If a post is deemed clear enough and specific enough to become a question, should there be a way to migrate it to become a question? Who are the right people to help determine if it’s ready to migrate?**

Comment: what exactly is "reply sorting" does it just sort between the first level of comments and leave the nested comments in order? Or is it for sorting the nested comments within each top-level comment? I can understand the first, but the second just seems like it'll be really weird for back-and-forth discussion.

Comment: @starball It will only sort the first-level replies. Nested replies will always show in chronological order.

Comment: Your ability to be so upbeat given the tenor of the feedback is admirable.  Still, as somebody who has been around for a while, I don't think I've seen an explanation for the problem Discussions is trying to solve that chat doesn't already serve?  (Please forgive me if this has been endlessly rehashed, but [the introductory post doesn't even seem to mention chat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) as near as I can tell.)

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Check out [this excellent question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392352) and our answer

Comment: Why do you expect curated discussions to have any more value than uncurated discussions?

Comment: what does it even mean to "migrate" a discussion into a Q&A? They're not the same format. And I doubt you can just find some comments and copy and paste them verbatim into a good or even valid Q&A pair.

Comment: @starball It's theoretical at this point, and we'd want to look at specific examples. For the purposes of the question, think about the post itself being migrated, not the replies.

Comment: @starball: I'd assume the idea would be to make it easy to convert an initial discussion post to a question – it might not make sense in all cases to port it over exactly as-is, but (for instance) the system could make it possible to prefill the relevant fields in the Ask Question page, or something of that sort. That idea has more to do with folks misusing Discussions to ask questions that belong in Q&A; it's not about converting genuine back-and-forth discussions into questions and answers.

Comment: Migrating the discussions to Q/A is not the best option. discussion that should be questions should just be deleted and poster notified why that happened. I have seen multiple discussion posts that were literally copy paste of previously asked questions by the OP. If we move such discussions we will just have more questions to close (as they are duplicates) and user will get closer to a question ban.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I don't think we'd invest in post->question conversion at this point, it would be more like detecting when a post (before or at time of submission) matches a question from that user. In terms of conversions, the question->post conversion, as part of question closure, is what we'd likely explore sooner.

Comment: I mean, it's no surprise that it'd be more palatable to drive content to discussions and not the other way around, ;)