# How can I retract a flag I raised on a Discussion?

Tags: support, status-deferred, flags, discussions-space

I raised a flag on a discussion in a collective to test out the flagging UI/UX assuming that I'd be able to retract the flag, and assuming that I'd be prompted with a dialog to select a flag reason after confirming that I wanted to flag it. Both those assumptions failed. I want to retract the flag and don't see how I'm supposed to do that. How?

Or if it's intentionally not supported to retract flags on discussions... why?

Comment: Have you checked your flagging history in your profile if you can retract it there?

Comment: @Tom you retract flags from the flag history page?

Comment: I think the tooling is just mostly unfinished there. I would assume there's eventually going to eventually be a flag dialogue where you choose a more specific reason (or really give any indication) why you're flagging.

Comment: Discussion flags aren't (currently) shown in flag history so that wouldn't help here even if it were possible to retract flags from that page (which it is not).

Comment: @HenryEcker Then how come I already retracted flags from that page which weren't retractable via reflagging that post? But could have been a user script, though.

Comment: @Tom the only thing the flag history provides is a filterable list of a users previous flags with their result and in some cases feedback. Any additional information, statistics, actions or other features would have to be a UserScript.

Comment: this would certainly be a nice thing to have, particularly now as it's site-wide and receiving more flag worthy content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this time, it’s not possible to retract a flag in Discussions.

This is intentional in the sense that Discussions is an experiment so the functionality is somewhat minimal. The flagging and moderation functions were created specifically for the Discussions experiment. The flags are not reflected in user flag history and are not part of the broader flagging functionality used for Q&A.

Certainly the ability to retract a flag is needed. Use of the [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) tag here is to indicate that much about the future of Discussions is still being determined and so this specific item is not on the roadmap.

Also, [this update on the Discussions curation conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426412/expanding-discussions-lets-talk-about-curation/426929#426929) may be of interest to anyone reading this.