# How do I view my flags in the ‘Discussions’ tab of a Collective?

Tags: support, collectives, discussions-space

A while back, I’d flagged a post in the Discussions tab of the Mobile Development Collective. I couldn’t find any option to track or view my flags. How can I view my flagged posts in Discussions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot.

See this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): [How can I retract a flag I raised on a Discussion?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426913/how-can-i-retract-a-flag-i-raised-on-a-discussion)

Discussion is an experimental features and it severely lacks curation tools. Based on the answer on the thread I linked, it seems that  moderation tools and features won't be implemented for them any time soon, hence [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred). Seeing a list of flags, knowing their fate (helpful, declined, etc.), retracting them, and so on won't happen in near future (especially, in the light of recent events). As of now, you cannot view your flags.

Answer (score 1):

For the Discussions experiment we do not have plans to add visibility into the outcome of raised flags.

There's no question that knowing the outcome of a raised flag is valuable to the flagging user. But it's an open question whether all of the rules and systems around Q&A flag outcome [tracking/feedback/repercussions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) should apply to this new content format in exactly the same way. Without reputation in the mix, the stakes for a given user for flags (on both ends of the process) are also a bit lower. So to keep development scope focused for the experiment, we did not integrate with or replicate the existing system.

Comment: IMO Everything in the second paragraph except the last part "_to keep development scope focused..._" is fluff / empty reasoning, you might as well not mention it...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat strongly disagree with your comment. Knowing that staff are aware of those "empty reasonings" carries weight.

Comment: @M-- It's not relevant that the flag outcomes might mean different for providing the user a way to track the outcome itself, regardless of what the outcome might mean the users would want to be able to track their flags so that point is moot. "_Without reputation in the mix_" there was never reputation in the mix for the flagging party I don't know why that even needs to be mentioned here. Adding these to the answer just looks like adding excuses, I'd have been fine with just the point that they want to keep the development focused on the experiment which makes much more sense.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat reputation point probably talks about the lower stakes in Discussions, not that flagging gives or takes reps. I read it that way, but I suppose that could have been worded differently. Your first point... I am not sure what's "not relevant". I don't think I agree with what you're saying, but then I am not sure I get what you're saying there.

Comment: @M-- as a user does whether reputation has anything to do with discussions matter to you for the purpose of tracking your flags? It doesn't to me. About the first point the point staff seem to be making is "We won't add capability to track flags since it is not clear if flag outcomes would mean the same thing to users" on the other hand my thought is "That doesn't make sense knowing the outcome would help the community figure out what the outcomes mean and how the guidance for the same should be made"