# Support programmatic detection and flagging of spam and rude/abusive content in Collectives Articles and Discussions (WebSocket and SE API endpoints)

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, collectives, api, articles

Currently, there's no method (without scraping) to automatically collect Articles & Discussions.

At one point [there was a way to get Articles](https://stackapps.com/a/10466), but it's since been removed from public functionality (and so non-functional).

Please add enough support so that programmatic detection and flagging of spam and rude/abusive content in Collectives Articles and Discussions can be performed. To do so, we need:

1. an API endpoint be added to fetch Collectives Discussions and Articles;
2. a WebSocket that gives information about new Articles or Discussions, including all similar triggers to "active" questions (e.g., creation, edit, and new Discussions reply), as if the Article or Discussion was a question (so polling for activity isn't required); and
3. an SE API endpoint for raising and retracting red flags on Collectives Discussions and Articles.

We need to be able to programmatically obtain the content that users' post and be notified when such content is posted or changed, particularly when posting that content doesn't required a non-trivial amount of reputation (e.g, the comment everywhere privilege).

Answer (score 2):

We have this noted as a feature request, both for future development on Articles and for a future Discussions product beyond the current experiment. At this time, API endpoints are not planned for either.

Comment: As of right now, there's ***over one hundred*** blatantly spam posts in Discussions ("blatant" meaning "almost certainly meeting SmokeDetector's autoflagging criteria"). Probably closer to 120 posts. And that doesn't include the blatantly spam replies, which are likely socks, that would likely also be eligible for autoflagging.  And this happened a few days ago too. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427664/16886597 Could the decision to defer this be revisited, please?

Comment: Update: the spam wave is still going, and has reached ***one thousand blatantly spam posts!*** While I'm looking forward to red flag deletion (planned for this month IIRC), I feel that API access for autoflagging would be quite beneficial, and should be reconsidered as a near-term goal. I suspect massive spam waves will continue unless there is automated and (near) real-time deletion of it (IDK about rate limiting effectiveness, considering socks).