# Please implement a rate-limit for discussions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, spam, collectives, discussions-space

There is currently a [spam wave](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/beta/discussions?page=1&pagesize=30) going on in Discussions which was [noticed here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56984945#56984945) by [Luciano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2885882/luciano). What is noteworthy here is that this spam wave is done majorly by only two user accounts and that they have posted many discussions within a minute. This wouldn't have been possible if we had proper rate-limiting implemented for discussions similar to what we have for [questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900).

Can we please implement suitable rate-limiting for discussions?

Comment: I've now cleared the 105 pending spam flags, deleted the 153 spam discussions posted in the last two hours and removed the accounts. It would be really great if this could be systematically prevented in the future.

Comment: @HenryEcker While I'm strongly opposed to spam, I would have been quite tempted to just leave them there for the CMs to clean up. SE chose to implement something without the moderation capabilities that are **minimally necessary** in order to control the spam/R/A problem that was virtually guaranteed to exist when they exposed a free-form textbox on such a large site. The community already goes a **long way** to clean up such things. I'm really frustrated that SE chose to make doing that cleanup harder, rather than putting enough in place for us to extend already existing processes.

Comment: There isn't one !? We really don't learn from past mistakes anymore, do we?

Comment: Somewhat related: *[Users are posting links to questions they want answered in Collective discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427689/users-are-posting-links-to-questions-they-want-answered-in-collective-disscussio#comment983195_427689)*. E.g., [from comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427689/users-are-posting-links-to-questions-they-want-answered-in-collective-discussion#comment983226_427689): *"There's not even rate limited on the feature"*

Comment: There seems to be another spam wave in the PHP collective

Comment: People use discussions/collectives? I don't see a problem with leaving this pointless feature to die. I took a quick look and it seems like it might be a useful honeypot for low-quality Q&A posts though.

Comment: @ggorlen: My thought too. As long as it doesn't turn up in search engine results.

Comment: [Latest](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/beta/discussions?page=1&pagesize=30): *"[Breaking News : IDF says troops located tunnel in south Gaza that was used to hold hostages](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/77796604/breaking-news-idf-says-troops-located-tunnel-in-south-gaza-that-was-used-to-ho)"*. It says (my emphasis) *"Threaded, public discussions on* ***technical topics"***. The current five collectives are *[CI/CD](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/ci-cd/beta/discussions)*, ...

Comment: cont' - *[Mobile Development](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions)*, *[NLP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions)* (***not*** [neuro-linguistic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming)), *[PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions)*, and *[R](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/beta/discussions)*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rate limiting has been put in place, and we're continuing to work on other spam-prevention approaches.

Comment: how does it work? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/997587 needs an update for this.