# Users are posting links to questions they want answered in Collective discussions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, discussions-space

Over the last little while, I've seen a number of posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions/77769368/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata). Most likely, that will be removed shortly so here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of example question]

Basically, a user encounters a question without a answer (or without an answer that's useful to them), so they make a Discussions post in an *"appropriate"* collective (actually, it's usually one that's so *not* appropriate it's a bit of a joke).

I've flagged these posts with a custom moderator message, something along the lines of:

> *"user needed an answer to a question, found a post on SO that didn't solve the problem but had the same/similar question, re-posted on Discussions in hope of a answer tailored to their exact needs*".

If this seems a bit exaggerated to you, I've asked a few posters, *"why does the linked question not work for you? Doesn't it cover the same error as you're encountering here?"*. Most posters responded along the lines of *"I couldn't get the answer's code to work, please help, I'm newbie, I have no idea what to do"*.

Ok, so maybe they need to do a quick bit of learning about the programming language they're working in, etc., so they actually *do* know "what they're doing". But most just post here in the hope that they'll get an answer quickly and easily.

I propose a new flag, maybe something like *"Re-posted question in an effort to get answer tailored to them"*, or something like that.

[Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) proposed flagging them as "this should be a question". I was opposed to this simply because it would cause more work for the moderators, and is quite roundabout, as stated by [VLAZ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427689/users-are-posting-links-to-questions-they-want-answered-in-collective-disscussio#comment983185_427689), but I can do this if necessary.

Comment: Have you tried flagging them as "this should be a question"?

Comment: @RobertLongson But if they were moved to being a question, they would be marked as duplicates of the original linked question.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Do you think that is an unreasonable outcome? If so maybe edit this question to explain why.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't see how the linked (and screenshotted) discussion *should* be a question. It lacks entirely too much to even be one. It lacks a question for one. The title has some error text, the body has a link to a question (unclear why it's there) and some code (ditto). The tags include [[tag:api]] where the guidance says "DO NOT USE". Not that it really stopped the hundreds of questions we get for that tag but still - I don't even know *why* the tag is there. Often it's at least added because it's somehow related to the text of the question. But not in the linked discussion.

Comment: @VLAZ Well once it's a question it can be closed as needs details or clarity, although I agree that discussions should also be closable as needs details or clarity directly.

Comment: If it's directly closeable, it sounds like it shouldn't be a question then. Flagging, so the post gets transferred to a Q (that's what I assume happens with a discussion), to be close voted sounds very roundabout and as if it's not the correct way to do something about the discussion. As if there is some sort of, say, feature request needed to improve the situation. On the main site we don't tend to reopen a question when it's known it falls under a different close reason. I don't see how discussions are so special they should get to go through almost an equivalent process to the one we avoid.

Comment: Isn’t stuff like that kind of the point of discussions? At the very least this doesn’t seem to break any rules.

Comment: At least for moderators, there's no method of moving a Discussions post to a question. As far as I'm aware, flagging a Discussions post as "this should be a question" is just providing a reason for why the discussion should be deleted (and maybe implicitly asking the moderator or CM to message the user, or leave a comment, letting the user know that discussions aren't the place to ask questions which would be appropriate on SO). Given that CMs are the ones that are *supposed to be* handling flags on Discussions, I'm actually not sure what they are doing in response to that type of flag.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I also don't see how the linked discussion falls under [any of the Encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines). Similar to how it doesn't have a question in it, doesn't even have any discussion point in it. What am I missing, what is to be discussed there?

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the insight. The *only* information related to that flag I seem to find is [the announcement that it was added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426929) (but not what it does) and [this issue that was brought before the release](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426648): "*If a post is deemed clear enough and specific enough to become a question, should there be a way to migrate it to become a question? Who are the right people to help determine if it’s ready to migrate?*" which suggests that *maybe* there would have been a process for making a question.

Comment: Welcome to Discussions.

Comment: Totally agree with what @VLAZ said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427689/users-are-posting-links-to-questions-they-want-answered-in-collective-disscussio#comment983185_427689). This does seem roundabout. I've updated my question.

Comment: It seems [the crypto currency scammers have found it](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions) (***WITH ALL CAPS TITLES***).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yup, I've flagged all the "discussions" and discussion replies.

Comment: @VLAZ The encouraged topics include "Discussions that expand on existing Stack Overflow questions/answers", which seems to fit perfectly. If instead the issue is that these posts are unintelligible, I am left wondering how apparently people can still deduce "Re-posted question in an effort to get answer tailored to them" - i.e. both the topic and even intention of the author.

Comment: I can only assume that discussions are working as intended now; they are for AI/bot Generated content to advertise scams. [So] has had *more* than enough time to address the problem, and cut staff levels instead of dealing with the problem(s). I can only assume that all this mess is intentional...

Comment: *Literally* the first page and a half (when set to **50** posts a page) of [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/beta/discussions?page=2&pagesize=50) is spam... Some of them posted by the [same user at the sme time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuvra.png). There's not even rate limited on the feature... If I wanted to see crap like that, I'd just into the junk folder of the email address I've had for around 25~ years and as been exposed in data breaches...

Comment: @ThomA Now it's entirely covering the first 4 pages. :D

Comment: Some of the responses to the rest look like generated by ChatGPT. [One with three suspected](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions/77723187/custom-mobile-app-development), with some evidence for two of them.

Comment: I think this is simply a duplicate. Only I have no idea how duplicates between discussions and real Q&A are handled.

Comment: This is just discussions working as intended by Stack Exchange Inc: a cesspool of fecal matter with more and more AI- and spammer-generated fecal matter constantly being added. It's almost like the community predicted this and was completely ignored, as usual.

Comment: First time I've ever looked at Discussions before, and I didn't see anything that was not actually spam.

Comment: It's nice how they use female names only for fake spammer accounts, as if this was somehow a technique to better camouflage themselves.

Comment: I suddenly realized why SO remained "mostly sane" for me throughout the years. It's because I never bothered giving Collectives and Discussions a look.

Comment: @iBug i mean, they have only existed for a few years at this point, discussions far less

Comment: The link is broken now. [Entry to Mobile Development](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions) on Stack Overflow Forums.

Comment: [List of X questions](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions/77750977/what-realistic-problems-do-people-wish-there-were-apps-for) aren't so bad.

Comment: I have seen [the misspelling](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions/77646045/where-and-how-are-xctest-beeing-execurted) "execurted" [recently](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=execurted) (though it could be a coincidence. Or a new trend in autocorrect systems). Within the last week.

Comment: [The Reddit feed](https://www.reddit.com/) is ***much*** more interesting than Stack Overflow Forums (after joining some appropriate subreddits). Some subreddits are overrun by the same kind of uninteresting content, but that is the exception.