# Can red flags on discussions nuke posts?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, discussions-space

Not too long ago, I requested to be able to [red flag discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427466/20153035). Well, we now can! Except the red flags don't act as red flags, as they can't bring down a post. Can this be fixed/added?

Comment: I implore you to just *imagine* my joy when I was able to indicate that "1-800-SPAM-SITE please visit my garbage website" was, infact, spam, but it *didn't actually do anything*, because the difference between flagging a discussion as "spam" and, as previous, without a reason at all, **is zero**.

Comment: Baby steps, people. Baby steps. But soon. SOON! We shall RULE THE WORLD! Or maybe nuke spam quickly and efficiently. I'll settle for that. FOR NOW!

Comment: It's like building a large city (discussions), and implementing a small police force (CMs). They can't be everywhere at once, so you let people report crime (flags). Then you let people say what the crime was (flag reasons). Now, we need to be able to perform a citizens arrest (red flags), as the crime is getting out of hand.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update: Jan 22, 2024** - we have implemented this. Red flags (spam and rude/abusive) trigger auto-deletion when a post has four of them (or one from a moderator).

---

We will be implementing automations as you describe, where posts will be deleted after six red flags, as with Q&A.

Comment: Are you going to use the site setting or have it be a separate configuration? I believe there are several sites (Stack Overflow included) that are using a number other than 6 for their threshold.

Comment: @HenryEcker I think that all sites are still on 4 flags ever since sometime during the strike.

Comment: *"We will be implementing automations"* When?

Comment: What about black flags? Could, for example, Greg Ginn raise those?

Comment: @HenryEcker thanks, I was using the [privilege description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a reference. We'll match the Stack Overflow Q&A flag threshold.

Comment: @Fastnlight in January, not yet sure of the exact date.

Comment: @user4581301 Submit that as a feature request and we'll see what we can do for Greg.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @Berthold If you haven't already, it might be reasonable create a ticket for someone to set that value up as a variable. That way the privilege page doesn't get out of sync with the actual threshold being used regardless of what ends up happing with the thresholds in future.

Comment: I'll accept this answer once the automations have been implemented

Comment: Also, @Berthold, is there any way to expedite this process? There are (at the time of writing) 3 spam posts sitting in discussions

Comment: @HenryEcker My thinking exactly and that's been noted.

Comment: @Fastnlight With the holiday-time pause in releases, it will have to be in January. As someone doing the moderating, I share in the eagerness to have this in place. The release this week does consolidate all flags onto a single page for processing (rather than just per-collective) so that will make checking and handling of flags more efficient.