# How can we deal with a user who posts multiple spam posts in Discussions?

Tags: discussion, spam, discussions-space

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23147236/padmapriya) user who has posted four spam posts in the [Discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/mobile-dev/beta/discussions) tab of the Mobile Development Collective. I’ve flagged all the posts.

Do I need to do anything else?

Also, what measures have been implemented to stop such a wave of spam by a single user?

Comment: flagging is the tool we have.

Comment: Related: [Can red flags on discussions nuke posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427514/15497888)

Comment: The *real* problem is the implementation of flags on discussions. Spammers know that, and so abuse it. Only the developers can fix that, but as they are too busy being made to shove AI related stuff down our throats, and add more stuff we don't want to collectives, fixing the problem is probably about as low a priority as getting the Staging Ground launched. /Cynicism

Comment: @ThomA /Cynicism Rather /Experience It's the way the company works. The real question is: should discussions really be moderated? Or should be maybe leave them to the company.

Comment: In general, technically you don't deal with a user; that's not what *we* do. You deal with content, so indeed flagging the content is your job done. Whatever needs to be done about a person behind the content is someone else's responsibility.