# Can we get a discussions flag-history?

Tags: feature-request, flag-history, discussions-space

I flagged some discussions posts as spam. (See this [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427689/users-are-posting-links-to-questions-they-want-answered-in-collective-discussion?cb=1#comment983195_427689) and [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427696/14998487) for more.) I expected the flags to be among my normal ones in the [flagging history tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/14998487), but none of the flags are listed there.

As it appears, the discussions-flags have not been integrated into the history. So could this be added?

Comment: Though the question is different, the answer still addresses the question; the ability to see your prior flags is [[tag:status-deferred]], and currently not seeing them is implied to be [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]] .

Comment: I'd argue that the implementation should be independently of the ability to retract flags. One should be able to see if and why a flag has been declined. Otherwise you end up with people that keep making the same mistake when flagging. No matter what direction discussions may involve, not implementing would create unnecessary work for all parties involved. (I therefore choose to decline the duplicate-close.)

Comment: From the suggested duplicate answer: *"The flags are not reflected in user flag history and are not part of the broader flagging functionality used for Q&A."* Yes, history and retracting are both needed, but my point is that the fact they are missing from the history is addressed in the answer; it's part of the same issue as if you can't see your prior flags, you can't retract them either.,

Comment: I see your point. However also from that answer: "…much about the future of Discussions is still being determined and so this specific item is not on the roadmap." As time and circumstances have changed, I believe it is needed to point out that the these features should very much be on the roadmap/implemented. Should you insist that keeping this post as is, is not the correct place to do so, I'll oblige.

Comment: The entire moderation toolset on Duscissions is a mess, @A-Tech. There's been probably 1,500-1,600 spam posts created on the "feature" in the last 12-16 hours.  Of course, some of us think that now it's full of AI Generated content, it's [[meta-tag:status-workingasintended]].

Comment: See: [How do I view my flags in the ‘Discussions’ tab of a Collective?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427314/how-do-i-view-my-flags-in-the-discussions-tab-of-a-collective) where a staff member has basically replied that they have no plans to implement this currently :(

Comment: Always sucks when a new product is released prematurely. You doom a chunk of your dev team to playing whack-a-mole on obvious problems that could have been dealt with in an organized, predictable, and above all budgetable, manner before release. Instead, the team wastes time on firefighting instead of dealing with the not-so-easily-predicted problems and implementing features for rev 2.