# New users posting spam with links in Collective discussions

Tags: discussion, new-users, spam, discussions-space

I have noticed a huge influx in spam posts, especially in the [discussion section of the PHP collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions). Most follow a similar format, with big headers at the top and then a link at the bottom. They are all posted by users with 1 reputation. Here's a sample:
[image: Screenshot of sample question]

Here are some other samples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77596500/my-friend-is-paid-35-dollars-every-month-imagine), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/php/beta/discussions/77596484/my-friend-is-paid-35-dollars-every-month-imagine).

I've flagged a bunch, but none seem to be being deleted, just being downvoted.

I think we need to crack down on this by not letting new users below 30 rep (or something like that) post questions with links. I feel this limit was in place before but has been removed now?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427358/how-to-prevent-question-asking-in-collective-discussions

Comment: There is a [plan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426412/expanding-discussions-lets-talk-about-curation/426929#426929) for improved flagging, which will hopefully allow these posts to be deleted by users, rather than having to wait for a CM to process the flags.

Comment: Honestly, this was only a matter of time. Since 1-rep users can post in discussions and flagging doesn't work well, discussions were bound to become a spam reservoir until proper flagging and support for tools like smokedetector was added

Comment: Why not allow spam in collectives?

Comment: Preventing new users from submitting links would prevent screenshots. Now an exclusion list could be used but they could just take screenshots of their spam (but they could do that today)

Comment: Preventing screenshots is just an added bonus.

Comment: Preventing screenshots would prevent asking genuine questions about the visual output of a program and genuine questions about G code in LabVIEW.

Comment: @DamianYerrick by far the most common use of links by new users is to post pictures of their code, rather than embedding the code in the question as text.  Eliminating those would definitely be a positive step.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah, totally. SO should try a filter for text like *"here is a picture of my code"*, etc.

Comment: @DamianYerrick Reasonable links can be put inline by editors with enough rep.

Comment: @SecurityHound : doesn't the SO main site only allow 1-rep users to include imgur links, not links in general?  And IIRC they can't embed images, only links.  (Doesn't stop some people from still only using that for their code, rather than a code block.  Also the required ratio of text to code might be the reason for some users omitting backticks around their code when they do copy/paste.)  Or maybe I'm just imagining this, since we do get spam *answers* with links sometimes on the main site.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this to meta. I've gone ahead and removed the posts and done some other cleanup. These Collectives Discussions are more or less in the trial phase and have the bare minimum implemented.

There is [tooling planned for better flagging support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426412/15497888), but currently it's just not there. Collectives are moderated almost exclusively by Stack Exchange staff members and while site moderators (like myself) also have the power to handle things it's not brought to our attention.

Flags typically feed into a moderator-only flag queue which gives the site moderation team a centralised place to view and review flags. Discussion flags, however, don't. Additionally, spam flags will automatically remove the post after a threshold is reached, but Discussions doesn't (yet) have spam flags so no matter how many flags a discussion receives it'll never be deleted.

What this means in practice is that a staff member (or site moderator) has to actively check each Collective for outstanding flags and manually handle the post. This aperiodic review (when someone remembers to check it) is just not happening frequently enough and this is resulting longer-than-expected handle times.

Anyway, thanks again for bringing this to our attention. I went ahead and handled all the outstanding flags for the PHP Collective while I was in there.

Comment: Instead of a person checking shouldn't it be easier to implement an automatic spam detector? It's extremely easy to see what posts are spam or not. And you could also filter off-topic questions and low quality questions. Something as simple as No code + Link could 99% of the cases be classified as either spam or a question that doesn't meet the standards, since the link usually is to an image of the code or an external site containing the code. Easy and saves a ton of time of downvoting, flagging and moderating.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Stack Overflow does have some spam protection mechanisms that are proactive (namely SpamRam) I don't know if this works with Discussions though. Not everything can be blocked reliably by automation though so some manual / reactive process is needed as well which basically works through flags.

Comment: Agree manual / reactive process is the most suitable for a final decision here. There are plenty of 500 rep users with access to review queues that could squash this like a bug.

Comment: This was predictable without a moment's thought.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt Yeah, but the problem is that few actually use the review queues anymore. I saw a post about this somewhere on Meta but I can't find this.

Comment: Why aren't the flags working?