# Do we need a tag for questions about the Discussions experiment, or is there already a tag for stuff announced in Stack Overflow Labs?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, discussions-space

The Discussions experiment was announced in July on the Stack Overflow blog and the Stack Overflow Labs microsite.

The Discussion experiment started on the NLP collective and was expanded to other collectives today. Currently, the Stack Overflow Meta questions have in common using [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives), but they don't yet have a specific tag as other initiatives do.

Any suggestion to name the tag in case more questions about the Discussion experiments appear? Should we use a more generic question for all new "experiments" to get more relevance in Meta, in other words, more questions?

---

Scanning questions tagged [collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives), I found one related question and a few tags. I added the link to the related questions and a section of related tags. I will leave the discussion of whether a new tag must be posted as answers and comments.

---

Questions about the Discussions Experiment (in chronological order):

- [Who is going to handle flags on content in the OverflowAI discussions feature?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425795/1595451)
- [Discussions experiment launching on NLP Collective](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426107/21769175)
- [The user research behind Discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426143/21769175)
- [Expanding Discussions: Let's talk about flag reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426412/21769175)

Related tags:

- [collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives)
- [overflow-ai](/questions/tagged/overflow-ai)

Comment: I don't think there's currently a tag for either Discussions in particular or Labs in general. If there does end up being a tag for Discussions, I'd suggest something like [collectives-discussions], since just [discussions] would not be very clear given the existence of the [discussion] tag. (I'm not taking a position on whether such a tag is necessary, though, either for Discussions in particular or Labs in general.)

Comment: @V2Blast [collectives-discussions] might work while the experiment doesn't be extended / migrated outside collectives. In other words, might be OK based on what was implemented so far, but it might have to evolve according to the vision, something that might never happen.  I'm not being negative, it is just that might that the project could take a different direction than what was envisioned before the experiments, as commonly happens with this things.

Answer (score 3):

The [discussions-space](/questions/tagged/discussions-space) tag has been created and added to five questions. The tag has a tag wiki.

Comment: I've renamed the tag to `discussions-space` (to make it plural, per the feature name). I've also added `collectives-discussions` and `discussions-feature` as synonyms of it.

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks. I have not caught yet how the "discussions-space" emerged... I wonder if this should be attributed to the tag creator, if someone suggested this explicitly, or just emerged spontaneously. If you or another thinks it interesting add this kind of details here, I'm OK with making this answer a community-wiki if that might work better than or together with the tag wiki.

Comment: Judging from the revision history of the questions it's now on, it looks like M-- was the one who added it, and wrote the tag excerpt and tag wiki for it. (It looks like [this question was the first one it was added to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/426107/revisions).)

Comment: I haven't seen this thread when I was creating the tag, but glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Update: Nowadays, **Discussions** is available for any Stack Overflow tag.

Source: [Discussions update: Expansion to all tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427864/1595451)

---

While the **Discussions** feature currently is restringed to Collectives, using [collectives](/questions/tagged/collectives) and the word Discussions in Stack Overflow Meta posts might be enough.

---

Some features are exclusive for Collectives that have their tag:

- [articles](/questions/tagged/articles)
- [recognized-members](/questions/tagged/recognized-members)
- [collections](/questions/tagged/collections)

It's not so simple to create a tag called `discussions` as we already have the required tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). There were tag clean project tagging problems in the past due to using singular and plural in tag naming. I don't recall if the solution implied preventing the tags from using the plural of an existing tag, but having a single-letter difference might cause problems.

Using a hierarchical / composite tag, i.e, `collective-discussions`, might be an option, but so far doesn't look to be necessary. On the other hand, it might not be the best option in the long term as the company has mentioned being open to the Discussions feature being available outside of Collectives. They have explained that it is being tested in Collectives to restrict it while the specific features are being tested and improved, and more features are being added.