# If this site isn’t a discussion forum in order for everyone to help each other, then what is it?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I got into a pretty heated discussion on one of these threads about whether 1) this site is a discussion site and 2) whether we can provide criticism of the site that isn’t squarely objective. So, with the hope of not getting blocked for not being objective enough, this is my question: why can we not provide criticism of bots and moderation enforcement policy? Further, what are we meant to do if we feel that this site has fundamental problems that need to be discussed, yet are being shut down by the people who run it? Both of these questions should have objective answers, so I look forward to the <s>discussion</s> answers that follow.

Comment: I suggested that Stack Overflow wasn’t a discussion forum, I didn’t necessarily, say that discussions were not allowed at Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: Again, discussions are fine in meta, and again, please accept any votes that this question may receive, be they up or down. I am not adding more, since I've pretty much said all that I wanted to say in the [previous related Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427224/522444)

Comment: Except you were criticizing us for discussing in Meta.

Comment: Again, I asked objective questions that should be able to be answered and yet I am getting down voted. So again I ask, where are we meant to discuss our criticisms if not on Meta?

Comment: "where are we meant to discuss our criticisms". On Meta. This post is based on a false premise, namely that you were not allowed to discuss on Meta. As the comments (mine included) under your previous post state, your post and comments were not components of a discussion. Discussions are allowed. Claims without reason are allowed, but discouraged, and disliked. Hostility is strongly discouraged. Sufficient levels of hostility are strictly banned.

Comment: if you want to change the site, understanding that status quo is strong will help. You need ARGUMENTS, not just "but I want it". The sites rules have been decided by the community after a lot of trial and error. For you to change stuff, you need to a) have a good argument why that would help the site, b) look if this has already been suggested, to be able to properly defend your suggestion, and c) have some humility that you MAY be wrong. You talk about discussions, but it seems like the only answer you want is "you're right", and you won't accept anything else. That's not a discussion :/.

Comment: Your posts add nothing to past discussions. So expect downvotes as unresearched & not useful & (since it's a meta site) disagreement/disapproval & closure as duplicate. This one included. And rudeness is never justified.

Comment: You are again bringing "bots" without any evidence, you get downvoted because people disagree with you, there are no bots involved there.

Answer (score 23):

Stack Overflow, like every other "main" site on the Stack Exchange network, is not a discussion forum, help desk, or anything else like that. It is a question and answer site, where the community collectively produces a high-quality library in the Q&A format. Each site has a templated [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that explains this.

Each "main" site has a corresponding "meta" site, and then there is also [a network-wide meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). These sites exist in order to figure out and explain policy, which inherently requires discussion. They are separated from the main sites specifically to keep discussion out of the Q&A area. Discussion is permitted here, which is why you were prompted to add a discussion tag to your question.

To criticize "bots", you would have to first provide concrete evidence of them existing. "People quickly downvote questions on Meta" does not qualify. Some users spend time keenly focused on the Meta question queue, exactly because of how important it is to try to keep everyone on the same page about policy. People who hang out here use their voting privileges very freely, because downvotes on Meta (by design) do not carry significant negative consequences for the user. In particular: except for meta.stackexchange.com you do not accumulate reputation, and your main-site reputation determines privileges here; it is difficult if not impossible to get question-banned from a meta site and it certainly will not impact on your main-site privileges.

Of course, Code of Conduct violations on Meta can still get your account suspended, which applies to the main site as well (perhaps network-wide; I don't recall).

If you feel that there are fundamental problems with the site, feel free to explain them here. However, you must still meet standards. In particular: check whether the issue has been discussed before; try to come up with a concrete, constructive proposal for addressing the problem; make sure that the commentary that you are about to offer actually constitutes part of a *discussion*; and try to understand policy before criticizing it. None of the rules, guidelines or policies here are arbitrary and the site is 15 years old; please try to respect the fact that the people who made these decisions had carefully considered reasons for them.

Above all, be prepared to receive an answer that effectively tells you that you have misunderstood something fundamental and that the fault lies there.

Answer (score 19):

Criticism of the system is absolutely allowed here on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) and on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Criticism of individuals or groups of individuals is allowed... until one crosses the line and breaks the [CoC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

However, please keep in mind that MSO has been around since 2014 and MSE since before that. Make sure you aren't retreading an existing discussion without addressing the fact that it's already been had and how the new discussion builds on the existing.

Comment: I would say that criticism of a person or group's actions would be the thing that is allowed. Criticism of a person... not likely to land well. "X incorrectly deleted my post" VS "X is a terrible mod and should be dropped". Yay to the former, nay to the latter.