# Why was my answer deleted without engaging me?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers, specific-answer, plagiarism

I'm a bit puzzled as to why my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77440539/changes-to-batch-script-resulted-in-failure-of-ffprobe-bitrate-reading/77499504#77499504) to a SE questions was deleted without further comment. There is just a laconic "One reason it's not useful is because the majority (if not the whole thing) is plagiarized" answer. Regardless whether "plagiarised" refers to being copied off somewhere or being considered the result of an AI, I have no visibility of what this claim is based on, and I can assure that it's not plagiarised. I have worked a bit with `ffprobe` recently, albeit not under Windows, but I can still understand and make sense of it. So this seemed a question to which I had an answer to. I have provided answers to the commented concerns as to why I proceeded.

**Please, explain what parts of my answer made you come to the conclusion that my answer is plagiarised!**

If moderators / the community decide to delete an answer it would be at least a common courtesy to get a reason and to engage the author before it's done. Otherwise, it all seems very much unstructured and on impulse.

While I had been with SE for a while, I'd consider myself still new as I've only posted the occasional question over the years – and frankly, haven't come across a shut-out closure like this before.

**A bit more engagement goes a long way.**

.

A screenshot composed from 6 separate screenshots is here:
https://imgur.com/a/jSUv1VL

Answer (score 15):

> Please, explain what parts of my answer made you come to the conclusion that my answer is plagiarised!

If this is about people thinking your content is AI-generated (a specific form of [plagiarism](/help/referencing), which is disallowed for [other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) on top of why regular plagiarism is not allowed on this platform), I don't think this should be done publicly (and I'd humbly ask the people doing so in the comments to stop). We're making a point to try not to let people know how we increase in confidence that something is AI-generated, because doing so would just help people who don't care about breaking policy to evade detection. See [this post by Makyen](/a/421889/11107541), and [this related discussion](/q/425578/11107541).

If your post was deleted because analysis of the nature of your content led there to be sufficient confidence that it was AI-generated- at least at the time that that analysis was performed, you should have received a message from the moderator who performed the deletion that that was in fact the case.

I can see that your answer was deleted by a mod. If you did receive such a message about AI-generated content, and you would like to dispute that analysis, you can reply to the mod message, or use the contact form, in which case the company's staff will investigate the mod action and work with the mods to understand that analysis and to resolve the dispute.

Note that in many (all?) cases, the non-moderator community has no *obligation* to engage with you if there is sufficient reason to believe that you have breached site policy, or it is obvious that you have broken site policy- policies which can be found in the [terms of service](/legal/terms-of-service), [code of conduct](/conduct), and [Help Center](/help). If you want to engage with this platform and be engaged with on it, at minimum, you would do well to read those resources to learn about what the site policies are, and why they exist. And then read relevant meta discussions here on Meta Stack Overflow.

Contrary to OP's view in the comments here, the methods for defining confidence that something is AI-generated are *not* subjective. They are concrete and thoroughly tested. See also [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391990/997587).

> If AI-generated content is such an issue here (and I never knew before today), then I think it would be good community engagement

This is part of the problem. You keep basically *insisting* on being engaged with, but you don't seem interested in first reading the community rules, guidelines, and norms as can be found in the ToS, CoC, Help Center, and Meta. This whole platform was built to avoid having to repeat things over and over. If you want to be engaged with here, you job is to first do your readings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did not receive a response by any mod about the decision made. I just found out this morning that my answer was deleted and since then am investing good time to find out what's happening and why. I am aware of the no-AI policy, and am reinstating that I have NOT used an AI here. The motivations as to why something is "classified" as AI generated seem to me to be very subjective. I know there are some telltale signs, but as I have stated in the comments above, if you read the OP's question, they're asking for advice …

Comment: …why the code breaks and I wanted to provide some insights into good coding standards. That's probably why my advice appears to be generic in nature and was assumed it must be AI-generated. That said, I will pay better attention to how I word my answers in future.

Comment: @AlexIxeras - Answers should be direct not generic, specifically, they should first and foremost answer the question that was posed. If the question cannot be answered the way it was answered with a detailed answer that answers it then the question should be improved

Comment: Thanks. It's one thing I've learnt now. Your answer here (and the comment above) is among a few actually useful answers. Too often people seem to twitch at the downvote button without further ado. I'm trying to learn and am probably as interested in SO being a useful platform as you are, but without proper engagement the platform will be losing engaged contributors (I read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427224/stackoverflow-is-no-longer-useful earlier). It's a reason for me, I quit Ask Different. I thought I could contribute to SO in a better way but need to rethink my answer style.

Comment: I'm getting more and more the feeling that the company-organised training for writing for audiences was taken off ChatGPT if it resembles so much its structure. Who knows what cheap trainer HR got?!

Comment: @AlexIxeras Please stop blaming the training. It is not the training's fault (if you ever had one). You were using AI plain and simple. You were lucky that you were not suspended. Now, that you know AI is forbidden, you should not use it in the future or you will be suspended. And forget about trying to pull some tricks, as it will not work.

Comment: @AlexIxeras - It wasn’t the training. Humans don’t generate content the same way a LLM does. Your answers contain numerous elements that LLM. A human, cannot write that way on purpose since they understand context.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I can't help but wonder why somebody would use AI to answer a question (with a few minutes of effort at best, if it was indeed AI) only to defend themselves in an extended manner like this after having their answer deleted. Who would want to engage in discussions like this where you're being called a liar among other things? It's a bit of a shame this style of answer is now frowned upon because I actually think they're quite easy to read and follow.

Comment: @Cuzy Wouldn't be the first time. We had blatant spammers arguing about why their posts were deleted. Just because someone is defending themselves does not mean they didn't do what they were accused of. Besides, it is not the style of answer that is the problem. There are plenty of answers using such style that are not AI.

Comment: I recently had this question opened; after a month, I checked recently submitted answers by the author, but there was no improvement after a month and a ton of feedback. Found two additional examples of generated content.