# Does this question need more focus?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, meta

Recently, I've voted to close a meta question, which got instantly reopened by a CM after reaching 5 close votes. The question I'm referencing is [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426412/expanding-discussions-lets-talk-about-flag-reasons).

This question is about curating the new "Discussions" feature, and asks about how to design the flag dialog. It explicitly contains a load of subquestions, such as "How should we deal with duplicate discussions?" and "How should we handle questions that don't belong in discussions?"

There are also a couple of implicit questions, that need to be answered when determining how to handle flags, like "Who will handle them, and confirm a discussion is a duplicate, or belongs better elsewhere?". On Stack Overflow main, this is often a point of contention, and requires subject matter expertise, so the current "CMs handle everything unilaterally" does not sound feasible to me if we want to flag duplicates and stuff that would be better asked in the Q&A section of Stack Overflow, even though it was fine for spam/rude/abusive content.

There's some content that hints that collectives should be self-governing, e.g. [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76946062/scope-tag-change-proposals-for-nlp-collective) on NLP. If the collective can broaden and narrow its scope by itself, that has consequences for these flags.

Another implicit question in my mind is "Should all discussion sections be handled similarly, or are collectives allowed some self-governance?" which is particularly important since we have some company sponsored collectives with a "not that great" track record in sticking to the rules. If we don't have consensus on this, designing a flag dialog seems silly, since we won't know if we need collective-specific reasons in there.

In my opinion, asking such broad questions is counterproductive to the discussion. This can also be seen in the answers, some of which only consider a single aspect, while others question the usefulness of the effort as a whole. If we want to properly discuss this, I think these points deserve separate discussions.

I want to figure out if I was in the wrong here. In particular, I'd like to know if questions asked by CMs are exempt to broadness rules, as [some](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) [more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425530/new-collective-nlp-scope-community-and-questions) about the NLP collective essentially contain a list of subquestion, which IMO deserve their own Q&A if we want to properly discuss each one.

Comment: It's an announcement, not a question. Yo Stack Inc. Put some effort into removing the close feature from announcements if you really do not want people to hit the button.

Comment: @Gimby It's both, and that's bad. If it was only an announcement, the close feature is fine, if people use it inappropriately we re-open, if they do so repetitively moderators can take action. Discussions should be discussions, announcements should be announcements, and if a single question is both that needs more focus.

Comment: Moderating much?

Answer (score 11):

*Please note that my answer only applies to meta discussion posts. It should not be used to justify anything on the main site*

As long as the sub questions are closely related to each other (which they imho are in this question), I see no problem with that in a discussion post. How else would you be asking them. You can't discuss how flags are handled without discussing who handles those flags. I'm also not sure if this specific question should really be seen as a pure discussion or more as an announcement from the company on the current state of designing a new feature which allows to give feedback.

I also think it's perfectly fine for answers to only talk about parts of the discussed points. That's what is happening in basically all discussions. It's rare that an answer on a larger discussion discusses all aspects. Most people focus on the on aspect they have something to say about.

I don't think that any of this is related to the fact that the question has been asked by a CM. Most of the other larger discussion posts on meta. Stack Overflow follows the same concept and has sub topics.

Side-note: I think it's counter productive to first complain that the company does not involve the community enough in designing the site and then close a post that invites such a discussion.

Comment: I do want to productively engage with this discussion, and am thrilled the company actually asks for feedback. It's just that in this form I'm entirely unsure about what is productive. I can suggest what I think should be moderated, and even suggest some dialog options, but with the current "everything is handled by CMs" I fear that some may not be handled by SMEs even though they should be and everything would become messy. I don't really know if that's up for discussion, since it's really focussed on the dialog. [1/2]

Comment: If they would just incorporate suggestions into the dialog, not thinking about a bigger plan on curation, we could end up with miscommunications and suggestions actually making stuff worse, not better. I could echo Makoto's "Moderating this is a paradox" since they appear to set themselves up for failure, but that hardly seems productive either. That left me with "this is too broad". I have yet to see existing equally broad discussions, only some more broad announcements or proposals, which this doesn't appear to be, it's focussed on discussing new flag options.

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like to know if questions asked by CMs are exempt to broadness
> rules

I'd say yes and it goes well beyond that too, although it would be **really** nice if the company would just come out and say that so we don't need to be making educated guesses about it. In the past that would happen because a person like [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) or [Tim Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/50049/tim-post) would respond to a post like this, and we're kind of missing that lately.

There are two signals on which I base my observation.

- The fact that the thing was immediately reopened. That is a hard overruling coming from the top and not you, me or anyone else has anything to say about that.
- The existence of the announcement tag gives a more "official business" note to the meta post.

It'd probably be great if there was something like an "official" tag though for things which are essentially read-only from a curation standpoint. Plus that this tag would trigger curation features to be limited to what our gracious hosts want to allow to happen on such posts.

It'd be so great if it would not be a confusing mess caused by no communication. Streamline this stuff, please. set up a guideline we can refer to. Do something beyond just overruling decisions people make to the best of their intentions and understanding.